# Scanning a polygon like geographical area

Tags: math, geometry, gis, geography, area

I have a geographical area that has a polygon like shape.  I want to scan that area with determined steps, say ~25-30 meters per step. I'm using lat/long system.  All I need is a way to do this type of scanning. Efficiency is a plus.

Also, If you can help me find a way to pick points on the border of this polygon with the same steps mentioned above.

**Note**: I don't care for 100% accurate results.

Comment: Are you using a particular platform?

Comment: I'm using RoR with Google maps

Comment: For those not familiar with RoR, what can you already do? (You're posing this as a math problem, not one about the particulars of a tool.)

Comment: Ya, I'm seeking a solution whatever it's. I'll find a way to transform it to my tool.

Comment: How many decimals do you have for lat/long? I need to estimate the errors in the calculations.

Comment: I don't understand your question well enough to suggest an answer.  How is your geographical area represented ? (Is it an ordered list of 'corner' points ?  A raster ?)  What do you want the scan operation to return ?  (A list of (lat,long) pairs uniformly distributed within the area at 25m spacing ?)  And a list of points along the boundary of the polygon at the same spacing ?

Comment: Best place to ask is here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @belisarius following http://www.zodiacal.com/tools/lat_table.php, we are at latitude 30 degrees north of the equator.

Comment: @High Performance Mark: I have a list of corner points. I need a list of pairs(lat,long) for points inside that polygon like area, considering steps of ~30 m. Also if I can get another list of points that resides on the boundary of that area that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you could:

a) Figure out the axis-aligned bounding rectangle for your shape.  Overlay that with a uniform grid, test each point in the grid for being interior to your shape.  A naive approach like this is sub-optimal, I am sure, but unless your shape is constrained (is it (strictly) convex ? does it have any holes in it ?) then it might be the simplest and most straightforward to implement.

b) You have the end points for each line segment in the boundary of your shape, it's fairly simple to divide each line segment into regular intervals.

Now, you have points specified in latitude and longitude and distances in metres.  If the bounding rectangle is small enough (this is a matter of your accuracy requirements but as a rule of thumb I'd suggest that if your bounding box is less than 30 arc-minutes along both sides it's small enough) just plough ahead and treat lat,long as plane coordinates, transform 30m into (local) angular measurement -- and bear in mind that the east-west and north-south angular measurements may not be equal.  For most of the populated parts of the Earth this will be accurate enough.

For higher precision, you will need to use some kind of projection, either to transform your geographical coordinates to plane coordinates to agree with your grid specification, or *vice-versa* (or both, since your inputs are a mix of geographical and plane points).

Comment: Yes that's worked: First to relief myself from the coordinates problem, I kept all operations using the sphere system. Second thing, I used a step of one second. After that I followed this logic: 1-Determine the bounding box 2-Generate a grid of locations in the bounding box 3- For each point in the gird, check if belongs to the polygon.  I found a cool algorithm to check if a location belongs to a polygon here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc451895.aspx.

Comment: The cool thing is that the whole problem was solved in less than 70 lines of code!